# Inserting a page break within a code chunk in rmarkdown (converting to pdf)

Tags: r, pdf, knitr, r-markdown, pandoc

I am using rmarkdown, pandoc and knitr to create a pdf including chunks of r code. Within a code chunk I have a for loop which prints a number of graphs and some statistical output.

I would like to insert a page break into the loop (to appear in the pdf output). This page break would occur after each graph is printed, to ensure each graph is printed on one page and the statistical output on the next.

I have been unable to find a way of including a page break in my r code chunk. I have tried `cat("\\newpage")` and `cat("\\pagebreak")` in the hopes it would be recognized by pandoc but to no avail (it is just printed verbatim in the final pdf).

Suggestions appreciated.  Here is the code I have so far:

````
```{r, echo =FALSE, message=FALSE, warning=FALSE, comment=NA, results='asis'}
library("markdown") 
library("rmarkdown") 
library("knitr")
library("ggplot2")
for (v in Values){

# read in file
testR <- read.csv(file.path, header=T)

print(ggplot(testR, aes(x=Time, y=Value, color=Batch)) + geom_point(size = 3) +
xlab ("Timepoint") +
ylab (v) +
scale_x_continuous(breaks=seq(0, 60, by=6)) +
ggtitle(paste("Scatterplot of Batches for ", v, sep="")))
ggsave(paste(timestamp, "__", 
       "Scatterplot of Batches for ", v, ".jpeg", sep = "")) 

cat("\\pagebreak")
writeLines(v)
writeLines("\n")
writeLines("\n Test for homogenity of slopes \n")
av1 <- aov(Value~Time*Batch, data=testR)
print(summary(av1))
}
```
````

Answer (score 42, accepted):

See below a reduced and reproducible example. The answer and some general remarks:

- To dynamically create new pages or sections in a markdown document use `results='asis'` in the chunk options.
- You have to add a linebreak (`\n`) after `\\pagebreak` or else `"ValueForV"` will be pasted directly after `"\linebreak"`, which results in an `Undefined control sequence` error.
- Make sure that `\newpage` and `\pagebreak` are in a separate line by using linebreaks `\n`  before.
- Escape `\newpage` and `\pagebreak` (i.e., `\\newpage`, `\\pagebreak`).

  ````
  ---
  title: "test"
  output: pdf_document
  ---

  ```{r, echo=FALSE, results='asis'}
  for (i in 1:3) {
    print(ggplot2::qplot(i, i+1))
    cat("\n\n\\pagebreak\n")
    writeLines("ValueForV")
  }
  ```
  ````

Comment: I'm afraid that still just prints \newpage, with an extra 2 blank lines in front of it

Comment: This is strange.. could you please edit your questions and provide a minimal and reproducible example?

Comment: I had forgotten to add results='asis' when calling the function itself. However now no pdf is produced and this error given "! Undefined control sequence.
l.105 \newpageDW"

Comment: First of all, please see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) on how to provide a reproducible example. It is really hard to find the errors if there is only part of your code. 

On topic: have you escaped `\newpage` (i.e., `\\newpage`)?

Comment: Okay so found the issue. As you can see in my code I was using writeLines(v) directly after cat which was creating \newpageValueForV. Inserting \n after \n\n\\newpage solves this. Do you want to adjust your answer to reflect such? And then I can mark as correct

Comment: Glad that you found it. I tried to adjust my answer accordingly and more or less summarised what to concider when dynamically creating rmarkdown documents.

Comment: This does *not* work if the output is `beamer_presentation`. Only for `pdf_document`.

Answer (score 3):

### How to insert a page break within an Rstudio .Rmd code chunk that survives conversion to PDF:

If the `\newpage` and `\pagebreak` latex macros aren't working for you, here's a workaround using HTML.

For example:

````
---
title: "The Rent"
output:
  pdf_document: default
  html_document: default
---

# This is pre-chunk text.

```{r, echo=FALSE, results='asis'}
print("Now we're <b>inside the chunk</b>, using the power of HTML.<br><br><br>!")

print("As you can see from the following diagram")
cat("\n")
print("The rent...<br>")
print(plot(1:10))

print("<P style='page-break-before: always'>")    #forced new-page happens here.

print("<h1>Is too damned high!!</h1>")
writeLines("\n")
print("Finished")
cat("\n\n")
```
This is post chunk text.
````

Produces this for me:

[image]

The key ingredients is the `print("<P style='page-break-before: always'>")` and the `{r, echo=FALSE, results='asis'}` in the chunk header.

Comment: I get `[1] ””` where the page break should be, but no page break.

Comment: @kmm same for me, no page break compiling the MWE provided by poster

Answer (score 0):

For beamer presentations, insert `{.allowframebreaks}` after frame header.

In this way, the LaTeX frame environment is created with the `allowframebreaks` option (i.e., `\being{frame}[allowframebreaks]`.

Then you can use `\framebreak` or `\pagebreak` or `newpage` to insert a frame break.

Make sure that the plots that are supposed to fit in one frame actually fit in one frame, otherwise beamer will put the plot in the next frame automatically. You can make a plot fit in a single frame with `out.height` and/or `out.width` options (see [R Markdown cookbok](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/figure-size.html)).

````r
---
title: "test"
output: beamer_presentation
---

# Test {.allowframebreaks}

```{r, echo=FALSE, results='asis', out.height="80%"}
for (i in 1:3) {
  print(ggplot2::qplot(i, i+1))
  cat("\n\n\\framebreak\n")
  writeLines("ValueForV")
}
````