# How to integrate \newpage with table printing in Rmarkdown?

Tags: r, r-markdown

Do you know if in R markdown you can use go to the new page without distorting print(df) ie. data.frame's printing? For pdf generation the simple example is:

````
---
output: pdf_document
---

```{r, results='asis', echo=F, fig.width=8, fig.height=5}
for (year in 1:10) {
    plot(1:year)
    df<-data.frame(rep("costam", year),1:year)
    cat("\n\n")
    print(df)
    cat("\\newpage")
}
```
````

Here, due to results='asis' the cat() command goes to new page; however, the data frame's are printed as strings.

- It is helpful if you want to print chart together with its summary for a long... long... list of charts then can do it in a neat standardize way.

Comment: Try using `print(knitr::kable(df, format="latex"))` instead of `print(df)`

Comment: Thanks, the printout is very neat and integrated with result='asis'!

Comment: This link will probably help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31830974/inserting-a-page-break-within-a-code-chunk-in-rmarkdown-converting-to-pdf